# AttributeError: 'Socket' Object has no attribute 'get_session_id'

Tags: python, sockets, session, openssl

I am getting this error when trying to retrieve the session_id from my current session. I guess this is deprecated from python3.x. Is there any workaround for this? Also, can anyone find and please post this def get_session_id() code from previous versions of OpenSSL, I cannot find it.
Thank you in advance!!

This is my calling code:

```
def _get_session_id():
    return self.ssl.get_session_id().encode('hex')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/HostShare/p4/ota-ite8-dev/testcaseRoot/default/ltm/profile/clientssl/secure_renegotiation/reneg_test_runner.py", line 279, in run_traffic
    c_recv, session_ids = self.client_reneg_triggers(
  File "/HostShare/p4/ota-ite8-dev/testcaseRoot/default/ltm/profile/clientssl/secure_renegotiation/reneg_test_runner.py", line 167, in client_reneg_triggers
    log.info(c_ssl.session_id)
  File "/root/support/lib/python/sal/interface.py", line 40, in <lambda>
    session_id = property(lambda self: self._get_session_id(),
  File "/root/support/lib/python/sal/openssl.py", line 310, in _get_session_id
    return self.ssl.get_session_id().encode('hex')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1630, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._socket, name)
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'get_session_id'


 

ERROR during client connection test:
Server SSL engine: openssl.
Protocol method: TLSv1.
Peer cert mode: 'CLIENTSSL_CERTIFICATE_MODE_IGNORE'.
Secure renegotiation mode: SECURE_RENEGOTIATION_MODE_REQUIRE_STRICT.
Reneg test properties:
{'dut_reneg_allow_state': 'STATE_DISABLED',
'exp_conn_exception': None,
'init_reneg': False,
'name': 'testcase check'}
ERROR: FailError("SSL Connection ERROR:'socket' object has no attribute 'get_session_id'")
SubTest 'TLSv1 == SECURE_RENEGOTIATION_MODE_REQUIRE_STRICT == testcase check 1' FAILED:
"FailError: SSL Connection ERROR:'socket' object has no attribute 'get_session_id'"
```